# Equilateral triangle with projection points.

Tags: geometry

An interior point of an equilateral triangle ABC is M. The projections of M on the sides of the triangle respectively: points E, D, F. Let G be the centroid of the triangle EDF. Prove that G is the midpoint of OM if O is the circumcenter of triangle ABC.

Comment: How is M projected on the sides? Does one drop perpendiculars from M to each side to get the three points E,D,F? If so which of these is on which side of triangle ABC?

Comment: e.g. MD is perpendicular to side AC, D can lie on side AC. and similarly MF perpendicular to side BC,  ME perpendicular to side AB

Comment: The midpoint of an  equilateral triangle is the circumcentre. (The point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors.)

Comment: Now the question is clear. Note that on this site a question will often get closed if the asker does not show some attempt to solve it, even if incomplete. I noticed your question has already 3 close votes.

Answer (score 1):

> An interior point of an equilateral triangle ABC is M. The projections
> of M on the sides of the triangle respectively: points E, D, F. Let G
> be the centroid of the triangle EDF. Prove that G is the midpoint of
> OM if O is the circumcenter of triangle ABC.

Note: This answer has been edited to take into account coffeemaths's comments.

This is the construction as described in your question, except it is the case of scalene triangle, rather than an equilateral triangle.

[image]

It is easy to see that G (the red point) does not in general lie on the midpoint of OM (The green point G' in the image) for general random scalene triangles.

However, when when triangle vertex C is aligned with point T to create an equilateral triangle (as specified in the question) point G does indeed appear to align with the midpoint of segment OM, (point G').

[image]

This answer is not a proof. It is just posted in support of clarifying the original question.

I will leave the analytical proof for others.

Here is the link to the [online interactive construction](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/jrfbwavw) for reference.

Comment: In the OP question triangle ABC is assumed equilateral. In your Geogebra diagram that triangle has only two of its sides equal, with the third off considerably, and if one moves one of the two lower points so as to make ABC become equilateral, then G and G' move into coincidence. So your picture supports the conclusion of the OP's statement, provided the assumption that  ABC is equilateral is imposed.

Comment: The question is interesting. But I don't think answer should be provided unless the OP has not shown any effort in solving the problem.

Comment: @coffeemath. My bad, I will edit my answer to reflect your observation

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Note that user KDP has not, as you say, "provided" an answer, but only a diagram which when investigated via moving points in it serves to support the question of smthBag. KDP did not supply a proof. [If a proof were given then I'd agree with your view regarding no work shown,.]